What was the fate of this character from the Reckoners?
At the end of the Reckoners trilogy, in Calamity, the character of Obliteration tells David where he will be in a week and what his plans are. Then the book ends. Is there any indication as to what happens with Obliteration and the Reckoners afterwards? Has Brandon clarified what happens anywhere, or promised a future book addressing this? I'm aware that there is an audiobook called Lux but it sounds like it's a spinoff, not a sequel. If the answer is in there, please use spoiler tags.

Not that I have a quote for a proper answer, but superheroes are kind of expected to keep fighting their villains off and on forever (except the odd team up to stop a greater threat)

No current answers.
Brandon Sanderson has not delved further into David and Obliteration's future since the release of Calamity.  As written, the scene could have been a sequel hook, but mainly serves to establish Obliteration sees David as a worthy opponent, and that few, if any, of his actions stemmed from Calamity's corrupting influence.
Lux, as you noted, is set on the same version of Earth as the Reckoners series, but follows a different cast of characters. Apart from Prof getting the group rolling there's little else to connect to David's crew.
Sanderson did plan a new series stemming from the Reckoners titled The Apocolypse Guard, but it hasn't yet gotten off the ground.  It was also intended to focus more on the multiverse aspects of the setting that Firefight could access, and possibly Calamity's source, so whether Obliteration would even show up in that plot would be anyone's guess.
